# TypeScript: refactor a part of JQuerified code to another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a big.js file which starts with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Inside this huge call to function I've a piece of code which I would like to refactor and move to specific.ts

I've tried both to write in the other file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#link").on("click", function(e) {
```

And directly the piece of code which I want to move:

```
 $("#link").on("click", function(e) {
```

In both cases I got errors like:

```
Could not find symbol 'jQuery'.
```

Comment: are you loading the other js file after jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific.ts file you need to either import jQuery or reference it

```
import $ = require("jquery");
```

or

```
/// <reference path="jquery" />
```

add to the beginning of the specific.ts file